# Unable to pass http headers through proxy Angular

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, cloud-foundry

I am trying to use a bearer token to get information from the Cloud Foundry API.  When passing the bearer token through the http header I get a 403 error.  It seems that when I pass the request through the proxy.conf.json the headers are not processed.

here is what i have in the PcfAppsService service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PcfAppsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPcfApps(): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get<any>('/v2/apps', {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'bearer tokenStringGoesHere'
      })
    });
 }
}
```

I can call the service with one of the components using:

```
constructor( private pcfApps: PcfAppsService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.pcfApps.getPcfApps().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

inside of the proxy.config.json i have the following:

```
{
    "/v2/apps": {
    "target": "https://api.scp1syspdv.schwab.com/v2/apps",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/v2/apps": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to overcome this issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: A 403 could mean a few things. It could mean the header's not set. It could also mean your token is expired. I believe you'd also see that if you don't have the right scopes, primarily `cloud_controller.read` or `cloud_controller.admin`. Are you able to spy on what's being sent through the proxy? or what arrives at Cloud Controller? It would be helpful to see exactly why it's saying Forbidden.

Comment: it works then i use a GET method on postman but when i put it on angular it wont take